# How to send cocos2d ValueMap to Java as HashMap?

Tags: java, android, c++, cocos2d-x

I have `cocos2d:: ValueMap`:

```
 ValueMap map;
 map["key1"] = "value1";
 map["key2"] = 1;
 map["key3"] = true;
```

**I want to send it to Java** as `HashMap<String,Object>`

So I wrote following code where I generate `jobject hashMapObj` and I want to populate it with values:

```
jclass hashMapClass= jniGetInstance.env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");
jmethodID hashMapInit = jniGetInstance.env->GetMethodID(hashMapClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject hashMapObj = jniGetInstance.env->NewObject(hashMapClass, hashMapInit, values.size());

//javap -s -p java.util.HashMap  | grep -A 1 put\(
jmethodID hashMapId = jniGetInstance.env->GetMethodID(hashMapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");

for (auto it : map) {   //https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/base/CCValue.h
    switch (it.second.getType()) {
        case cocos2d::Value::Type::BOOLEAN:
            jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapObj, hashMapId, "put",
                                                 jniGetInstance.env->NewStringUTF(
                                                         it.first.c_str()),
                                                 it.second.asBool());
            break;
       //...

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And I get crash in line:

```
jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(
   hashMapObj, 
   hashMapId,
   "put", 
   jniGetInstance.env->NewStringUTF(                                             
               it.first.c_str()),
               it.second.asBool());
```

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0xd85d4aa0

**Edit**

```
jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapObj, hashMapId, "put","someString", true);
```

fails with the same error so problem is with `hashMapObj`

Any ideas?

Comment: Just wondering why not send it as a JSON String so that you can package it to HashMap in java...

Comment: @RRTW because on Java side I have API that receives `HashMap` only

Comment: is `boolean` same as `java.lang.Boolean`? is `boolean` an object? Is any primitive data type an object? ... Did you tried to create and put there `java.lang.Boolean` ?

Comment: Send it as JSON, create a new JavaAPI to package it as HashMap, and pass it to your existed HashMap only API, I think this is the most quick and low risk way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapObj, hashMapId, "put",
    jniGetInstance.env->NewStringUTF(
        it.first.c_str()),
        it.second.asBool());
```

to

```
jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapObj, hashMapId,
    jniGetInstance.env->NewStringUTF(it.first.c_str()),
    it.second.asBool());
```

since "put" method accepts only 2 args.

Also make sure that `it.second.asBool()` returns `jboolean` - it differs from C++ `bool` type.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, however it still fails with error: `JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale Local 0x1 (should be 0x9)
10-11 15:15:33.662 28123-28540/com.snaggs.cocos2dX A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x1`

Comment: Then you may need to wrap `it.second.asBool()` into `Boolean` java object. Also do not forget to call `DeleteLocalRef` for all objects created locally (`HashMap`, `String` and `Boolean` in your case) after use.

Comment: Yes, I know, maybe HashMap expects `java/lang/Object`? I tried directly write : `jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapObj, hashMapId,"xxx","ssss");` but still fails `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0xd86d1af0`

Comment: You are right, this one works: `jniGetInstance.env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapObj, hashMapId,jniGetInstance.env->NewStringUTF("xxx"),jniGetInstance.env->NewStringUTF("ssss"));`

Comment: "xxx" and "ssss" are not java objects, just string literals. To create objects you need to use functions `NewStringUTF` and `NewObject`.